# Array are not selecting values randomly and split into two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have got an array list of animals, on click on 'select' button I
would like to randomly select these animals and pass animals into two
 arrays (split) called 'teamA and teamB'. Here is my code, but I am getting the same array list always as per screenhot link ? Could someone please
 help me to figure out the problem ?

```
    import java.lang.Math; 
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import java.util.Random;

    public class RandomExample {

        private Random random = new Random();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
  // 'list' array list contains animals
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Tiger");
            list.add("Crocodile");
            list.add("Cat");
            list.add("Dog");
            list.add("Elephant");
            list.add("Lion");
            list.add("Deer");
            list.add("Eagle");

            RandomExample obj = new RandomExample();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
               obj.getRandomList(list);
               List<String> teamA = list.subList(0, 4); 
               List<String> teamB = list.subList(4, 8); 
              System.out.println(teamA); 
              System.out.println(teamB);             

            }

        }

        public String getRandomList(List<String> list) {

            //0-4
            int index = random.nextInt(list.size());
            System.out.println("\nIndex :" + index );     
            return list.get(index);

        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Just a quick question... You are returning a string from getRandomList() but you never use it. What is the purpose of getRandomList if you don't use the returned value?

Comment: @JohnG Note that it's public, it is most likely used externally by some other classes

Comment: @Simon Jensen Not sure if I follow. Yes the method is public, however the OP does not use the returned value with `obj.getRandomList(list);`. I was asking why they did not capture the returned string. Otherwise the randomness is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I asked I am not sure why you do not capture the returned string from getRandomList()… I am guessing you are thinking that the list gets returned? Another issue is that when you get a random number from the list you could get the same number. Therefore you will possibly get the same animal on both teams or even the same animal twice or more on the same team. When you put an animal on a team… you need to remove them from the list.

Below I create the two teams. Then setup two loops, one for each team. Using your getRandomList method to get a random animal then remove that animal from the list. After we have both lists, print the results. Hope this helps.

**Edit: As per OP request to have a different number of animals for the teams.**

Example: use 5 total animals for the teams.

Obviously it’s better to look at the amount of available data before you actually set the team sizes. Example: if you want teamB to have 5 and teamA to have 4, then there better be at least 9 animals in the list. So check the team sizes before you start the loops. If `totalAnimalsForTeams` is greater than the number of animals in the list or `totalAnimalsForTeams` is less than two , then we need to indicate this to the user and exit. This approach allows you to use only part of the list if needed.  In the implementation below, if the `totalAnimalsForTeams` is an odd number the second loop will have the extra animal member.

```
public class Main
{
  private static Random random = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      // 'list' array list contains animals
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      list.add("Tiger");
      list.add("Crocodile");
      list.add("Cat");
      list.add("Dog");
      list.add("Elephant");
      list.add("Lion");
      list.add("Deer");
      list.add("Eagle");
      list.add("Monster");
      list.add("Alien");
      list.add("Vombie");
      list.add("Politician");
      list.add("Donkeye");

      List<String> teamA = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> teamB = new ArrayList<String>();
      String newAnimal;

      int totalAnimalsForTeams = 7; // <- probably get this value from the user?

      if (totalAnimalsForTeams > list.size())
      {
          System.out.println("There are only " + list.size() + " animals in the list. Requested animals was: " + totalAnimalsForTeams);
          return;
      }

      int firstHalf = totalAnimalsForTeams / 2; 

      if (firstHalf < 1)
      {
          System.out.println("Requested " + totalAnimalsForTeams + " animals for teams... not enough to make two teams!");
          return;
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < firstHalf; i++)
      {
        newAnimal = getRandomList(list);
        teamA.add(newAnimal);
        list.remove(newAnimal);
      }

      int secondHalf = totalAnimalsForTeams - firstHalf;

      for(int i = 0; i < secondHalf; i++)
      {
        newAnimal = getRandomList(list);
        teamB.add(newAnimal);
        list.remove(newAnimal);
      }
      System.out.println(teamA); 
      System.out.println(teamB);             
  }

  public static String getRandomList(List<String> list) {

      //0-4
      if (list.size() > 1)
      {
          int index = random.nextInt(list.size());
          //System.out.println("\nIndex :" + index ); 
          return list.get(index);
      }
      else
      {
          return list.get(0);
      }

  } 
}
```

Comment: if the array items / size are not equal while splitting, what is the best way to handle ? In above example if there were 9 items, I would like to split into 5 and 4

Comment: @soccerway Updated the answer to allow you to use a different number of TOTAL animals for teams.

Answer (score 0):

try this .. it should work ..

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomExample {

    private Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Tiger");
        list.add("Crocodile");
        list.add("Cat");
        list.add("Dog");
        list.add("Elephant");
        list.add("Lion");
        list.add("Deer");
        list.add("Eagle");

        RandomExample obj = new RandomExample();
        List<String> teamA = list.subList(0,4); 
        List<String> teamB = list.subList(4,8); 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            obj.getRandomList(list);
            teamA = list.subList(0,4); 
            teamB = list.subList(4,8); 
            Collections.rotate(teamA, 1);
            Collections.rotate(teamB, 1);
            System.out.println(teamA); 
            System.out.println(teamB);          

        }



    }

    public String getRandomList(List<String> list) {

        //0-4
        int index = random.nextInt(list.size());
        System.out.println("\nIndex :" + index );     
        return list.get(index);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `obj.getRandomList(list);` returns a `String` but you donot do anything with it. I know this method is supposed to return a randomly picked item.

> 1. To correctly do what you are asking for, You would have to declare a new `ArrayList` say `temp` and then assign `list` to it.
> 2. To avoid Repetition of the same object, you need to remove the randomly generated item from the `temp` ArrayList created.
> 3. Then after you are done, remove the `temp` ArrayList created.

I have made the necessary changes to your `main` method as per the suggestions I made.

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            // 'list' array list contains animals
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Tiger");
            list.add("Crocodile");
            list.add("Cat");
            list.add("Dog");
            list.add("Elephant");
            list.add("Lion");
            list.add("Deer");
            list.add("Eagle");

            RandomExample obj = new RandomExample();
            List<String> teamA = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            List<String> teamB = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> temp = list;

            String animal;

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                if(temp.isEmpty() == false){
                    animal = obj.getRandomList(temp);
                    if(i <= 3){
                        teamA.add(animal);   
                    }else{
                        teamB.add(animal);
                    }
                    temp.remove(animal);
                    //System.out.println("temp is "+temp);
                }
            }
            temp.clear();
            System.out.println(teamA); 
            System.out.println(teamB); 

        }
```